# Ajax how to disable div or item

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to ajax, is there a way you can help me, how to disable all items once click is successful:

Here is my code for ajax:

```
if (!parent.hasClass('.disabled')) {
    // vote up action
    if (action == 'click') {
        alert("test");
    };

    //how do i add disabled function on a particular div

    // add disabled class with .item
    parent.addClass('.disabled');
};
```

here is my index:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
    <div class="item" data-postid="<?php echo $row['recipe_id'] ?>" data-score="<?php echo $row['vote'] ?>">
        <div class="vote-span"><!-- voting-->
            <div class="vote" data-action="up" title="Vote up">
                <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
            </div><!--vote up-->
            <div class="vote-score"><?php echo $row['vote'] ?></div>

        </div>

        <div class="post"><!-- post data -->

            <p><?php echo $row['recipe_title'] ?></p>
        </div>
    </div><!--item-->
```

i jst want to disable the loop icon-chevron-up class.not just one but all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no ajax call needed here. I will only be done by using jquery. See the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').click(function(){
        if (!parent.hasClass('.disabled')) {
            parent.addClass('.disabled');
        }
    });    
});
```

Here you have not mentioned, on what click you need the action, so i consider that on the div contains class='item', the action will be performed. I hope it will help.